# 404 error - page loads fine. OSCommerce - Seperate WP install on blog.

Tags: seo, javascript, 404, java

I have looked over other peoples posts but I cant find anything to fix this specific error.

On my site, I have 2 CMS - one for the main site which is OS Commerce and I have Wordpress installed on the blog.

My blog page:

pmctelecom.co.uk/blog/

If you right click (on chrome) > inspect element > console it is returning 404 errors, and I think this is causing a lot of internal link issues.

I can see here: " https://www.pmctelecom.co.uk/PMC%20Telecom Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

That this is the broken link. (https://www.pmctelecom.co.uk/PMC%20Telecom)

My .htaaccess has this line:

RewriteRule ^PMC%20Telecom$  /  [L,R=301]  this does not seem to redirect PMC%20Telecom to /home as expected, but I have other redirects that work fine in the htaccess file.
Any ideas? I have seen somebody suggest use Wp-DBmanager, but if I put in FTP pass on any wp plug-in, it just simply dosn't take it.

Additionally it seems every other page on the site that directs to blog gets a 404 when they arrive - though the page loads fine.

can anyone please advise?

Comment: Is your Wordpress installed in a folder called "blog" that is inside your OS Commerce directory?

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht yes it is

Comment: @nathanangiesbrecht It goes root>httpdocs> blog > in here lies wp admin etc - any ideas ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need any rewrites at all. I work with basically an identical setup. I just dropped the WP install into htdocs/blog and everything was accessible from domain.com/blog If you need the re-write for some other reason, I think you'll need to escape the space instead of encoding it. ie. "PMC\ Telecom" per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410811/mod-rewrite-with-spaces-in-the-urls

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht I need those for other reasons. Anyhow this is not good advise based on the above :)